# How to arrange Pandas dataframe based on all row values positive, one row values negative, two row values negative ... and all row values negative,

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to arrange Pandas dataframe based on all row values positive, one row values negative, two row values negative ... and all row values negative,

```
df=pd.DataFrame({
                 'x':[1, 2, 3, -1, -2, -3],
                 'y':[-1, 3, 2, -4, 3, -2],
                 'z':[1 , 1, 5, 2, 1, -1]}]
```

**expected output**

```
index  x  y  z 
1      2  3  1   all positive  
2      3  2  5    
4     -2  3  1    one  negative
0      1 -1  1
3     -1 -4  2   two  negative
5     -3 -2 -1   all negative
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

It gets the rows that are greater than 0, sums them across the columns, then based on the values, sort in descending order (all positive should be the highest, followed by one negative, two negative, and all negative). After the sorting, the `num` column can be dropped, as it has served its purpose.

```
(df.assign(num=df.ge(0).sum(1))
 .sort_values("num", ascending=False)
 .drop(columns=["num"])
 )

    x   y   z
1   2   3   1
2   3   2   5    
4  -2   3   1
0   1  -1   1
3  -1  -4   2
5  -3  -2  -1
```